# Identify this sci-fi movie in which a scientist and his family move into a new house

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I've been trying to identify this movie for years now and just now thought of StackExchange. :)

So here's all the things I can remember about the plot:

- **Scientist and his family move into new house in a new city**
- I think the mother and son drive there first and the father follows a little later
- The city is surrounded by desert, or at least very dry surroundings
- I'm really not sure, but I think something happened to the world in this movie, like the sun is extremely intense or something
- The father sets up his lab in the basement with all kinds of lab equipment
- Their neighbour MIGHT have a daughter at the same age as their own son
- Teenage son gets bullied in school
- At one point the bullies tie him to some kind of statue (it also might have been a sun dial or something like that) in the schoolyard, he gets a really strong sunburn and the girl saves him (as I said, something is wrong with the world and the sun burns very strong)
- He and the girl become friends (maybe become a couple, can't remember)
- Not sure, but I think they steal the car of the girl's father and take it for a ride at one point

Now here's the freaky/sci-fi stuff:

- The son's **father** (the scientist) does some really weird experiments in his lab and somehow **turns himself into some kind of flying energy/nature wizard/higher being** (*sorry, I know this sounds weird*)
- The mother is very friendly as far as I can remember and also a environmentalist
- She keeps telling her son about how good certain plants and trees are
- Somehow there's **plants, mold spores and moss growing everywhere INSIDE the house** (most definitely has something to do with the father's experiment)
- The whole house becomes its own little ecosystem and is "alive"
- The neighbour can't stand all the plants and stuff and freaks out when he is inside the house at one point
- He wants to burn all the plants etc. and talks a few other people into helping him
- The house traps and kills some of the people
- The army or some law enforcement agency get involved as well

The movie is probably from the 80s, but I'm really not sure, could be from the 90s just as well.
I guess I've seen this about 8-10 years ago.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the movie other than what was in it?  What country was it from?  Was it a feature film, or just made for TV?  Could it have been just a TV episode?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot about that. I'm almost 100% certain it takes place in the USA. I don't think that it was an episode of some TV series. The way I remember it, I would say it has that 80s trash movie look, but other than that it's a really good movie.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Habitat](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119243/), (1997), with Alice Krige, the future Borg Queen.

> In a future world where Earth's ozone layer has been completely
>   destroyed, a brilliant but obsessed scientist, Hank Symes uses
>   illegally obtained biological materials for an experiment that he
>   hopes will save the world. In the course of his work, a terrible
>   accident occurs, transforming him into a fantastic otherworldly
>   lifeform and changing his house into a huge living entity which
>   threatens all who enter.